# Terms, keywords, tags hashtags this is confusing

Tags: sharepoint-online, metadata, term-store, tags, hashtags

i have read all day about keywords, tags, #hasttags and it confuses me. Whats the difference between Keywords and terms/termsets?

I have tagged documents with keywords, but i want to use terms instead so i can build a structure in termstore. Like this:

```
      Countries

      England - London
      Sweden - Stockholm
      France - Paris
```

Then i can choose to tag a document with ex. "London", becouse with keywords i can add any "under heierarchy", how can i acchieve this?

Answer (score 10):

**Terms** are the basic unit or smallest item in Managed Metadata or Taxonomy. **TermSet** is just a collection of Terms.Like say if you want to create a taxonomy for countries and their cities.
Country will become the TermSet (eg:England) and cities will be Terms inside respective termsets ie London will be term inside England.

**Tags** are special terms , they are stored inside **Keywords** termset  in a internal  taxonomy group **System**. You can add tags to documents and pages.After tagging with the help of **tag cloud** you can easily track documents, pages and other activities.

**#HashTags** are again special terms stored in **HashTags** Termset in System taxonomy group.#Hasttags can be used in newsfeed , blog posts, discussions etc, to make them more social.It is very much similar to twitter,FB social hash tags.

OOTB tags &  Notes always works with **Keywords** termset and hence you can only create tag and add tags from **Keywords** termset only.

See this article for [Tags & Notes](http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/sharepoint-server-help/use-tags-and-notes-to-share-information-with-colleagues-HA101810816.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for information. Lets say an organisation wants to have predfined tags that are in a hierarchy, and users are not allowed to add new tags. They also want to use them to tag things/sites etc Then i must use Terms and not keywords?

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/94595/tagging-with-terms-or-with-keywords/94609#94609 Check this

Answer (score 6):

The big difference between Keywords and Terms are that Terms are controlled by you (normally) and Keywords are controlled by the users. Sometimes Keywords are referred to as Folksonomy whereas Terms are referred to as Taxonomy. To use Terms to tag a document, create a custom Site Column and map that to a TermSet (which is a collection/hierarchy of Terms), and don't use the default Keywords column.

Comment: A very good distinction between terms and keywords. If you don't mind I'll borrow this one from you :-)