# Tagging with terms or with keywords

Tags: term-store, tags

I have a hierarchy of words that I want the users in my site to tag things with. I do not want them to create their own words

Should I create my hierarchy with termsets in termstore or should I go with keywords? But keywords dont allow me to create an hierarchy

What's a good option here?

Answer (score 1):

**Tags** are associated with in built **Keywords** termset. You can create predefined tags but it won't be in hierarchical order.You can open managed metadata service , go to **System**-->**Keywords**. Add your pre defined terms.
Also to restrict the user from adding new tags you can select **Keywords** termset and in General tab in right side set **Submission Policy** to **Closed**.